# 405 - Method not allowed , cant get a solucion

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post

I'm making an webapp. In this webapp im using a webservice that was already made. Before i started to develop this app for the web , i make the exact same in java for android and everything of the post requests worked fine but in this web app it doesen't. Also in postman works like a charm.
Can someone help me to figure out thats wrong?
Here is my code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");

session_start();


$totalPrice = 0;
$itemTotal = 0;


if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
        echo '<li>';
        // Output item details
        // For example:
        echo 'Código: ' . $item['codigo'] . ', ';
        echo 'Descrição: ' . $item['descricao'] . ', ';
        echo 'Preço: ' . $item['preco'] . ', ';
        echo 'Quantidade: ' . $item['quantidade'];
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'O carrinho está vazio.';
}

echo '<p>Total a pagar: ' . $totalPrice . '€</p>' . '<br>';


if (isset($_POST['fazerEncomenda'])) {
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo 'Utilizador não está logado.';
        exit;
    }

    
    $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    // THE PARAMETERES ARE FIXED FOR NOW 
    $order = array(
        "FiscalYear" => "2024",
        "SectionCode" => "1",
        "DocTypeAbbrev" => "ENCCL",
        "EntityCode" => 1,
        "Date" => "09/02/2024",
        "ExpirationDate" => "08/12/2024",
        "CurrencyCode" => "EUR",
        "Lines" => array(
            array(
                "LineNumber" => 1,
                "ItemCode" => "1",
                "ItemDescription" => "artigo teste",
                "Quantity" => 1,
                "VATTax" => 23,
                "UnitPriceExcludedVAT" => "1",
                "GetReportBytes" => true
            )
        )
    );

  
    $ch = curl_init('http://myip/ERPV22/api/EncomendarUser/GenerateCustomerOrder');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($order));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Cookie: PHPSESSID=' . session_id() 
    ));

    
    $decodedCookies = urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $decodedCookies);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response; 
}
?>

<form method="post"> 
    
    <input type="submit" name="fazerEncomenda" value="Fazer Encomenda">
</form>
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I dont see any syntax issue with the snippet you have provided the 
error you have provided is 405 - Method Not Allowed 
This occurs when the HTTP method being used to make a request to a resource is not supported by that resource.
So you should try to check the endpoint you are posting the request to. Sometimes it works on Postman and Android app but Server configurations or API gateways might behave differently based on the origin of the request.
kindly use error handling for cURL